# Is it possible to deploy specific Java dependencies to nodes on Hazelcast Cloud?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

I'm submitting Java runnables to hazelcast executor service, the runnables need access to specific business objects and also to hazelcast client.

Is there any way to deploy a hazelcast cluster on hazelcast cloud with specific dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@newlogic, according to [Hazelcast Cloud Documentation](https://docs.cloud.hazelcast.com/docs/release-notes#section-march-15-2019), User Code Deployment feature is enabled. All you need to do is to enable it on the client as well & configure it, as documented here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#client-user-code-deployment-beta